# prevent certain column values from returning when calling an active record instance (without limiting access to them in future)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, terminal, spatial, awesomeprint

I have a database which is postgis enabled which has some records (in a given table, there are many) that have enormous `:spatial` column values.

I often use the `awesome_print` gem to view records quickly while working. It colorizes and nicely displays a given record (or records') information for quick review. The problem in this case is that 99% of the terminal display is devoting to showing these spatial column's multi-page length list of coordinates in the WKT format.

I'd like for activerecord to not return these objects when viewing these with the `ap` (awesome print) command. Is there any way to do that without breaking something else? Can I just instruct ActiveRecord to hide these column's values unless specifically requested or is that too much to ask?

Comment: may be this would help : http://icelab.com.au/articles/customising-activerecords-attribute-formatting-on-inspect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another you need to designate which fields to print, or not to print. For instance you could define a helper for this and put it, say, in the your console config file, e.g.:

```
def ap_article(article, cols=%w[col1 col2 col3])
  ap article.attributes.slice(*cols)
end
```

or perhaps something like this if you just want to ignore the spatial columns

```
def ap_article(article)
  cols = article.class.columns.select {|c| c.type != :spatial}.map(&:name)
  ap article.attributes.slice(*cols)
end
```

Comment: thanks! nice use of the bang operator I hardly use that currently but good example to start with